# Roll back version

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

We have published an application to the store, currently with  status

> Ready For Sale.

However the client doesn't want to, so what is the right process and is it possible to roll back to the previous version ?

What other options do we have.

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Select your app in iTunes Connect.
- Go to Pricing and Availability in the App Store and Information
  section.
- Click Remove from Sale under Availability.
- Click Save.

It is not possible to revert the app version, you should upload the previous version as new version again to fix this.

Comment: And does the previous version come up to the store ? and when i want to republish it what should i do

Comment: You will need to submit a new version of the app.

Comment: it is not possible to revert the app version, you should upload the previous version as new version again to fix this

Comment: could you add those comment as a part of the answer, might be useful for others